# Assign the same color choosen randomly from an array to all element with the same class

Tags: javascript, css, function, math, random

I have this function to assign the same color choosen randomly from an array to all elements with the same class but the elements get different colors at same time. 
Now the function works but each h2 element get different color.
I would like to have that all the h2 element with "change_color" class get the same color every time.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var colors = ["#FFB24A", "#ED145B", "#55D3D2", "#E8390F", "#787878"];
jQuery(".change_color h2").each(function() {
    jQuery(this).css("color", colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
});
});
```

What do I need to change to apply the same color to all the elements?
Thank you.

Comment: `jQuery(".change_color h2").css("color", colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have implemented calculates the range for each iteration. First, you need to get the random color, then you assign to all H2.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ["#FFB24A", "#ED145B", "#55D3D2", "#E8390F", "#787878"];
    var randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    jQuery(".change_color h2").each(function() {
        jQuery(this).css("color", randomColor);
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the loop for? `jQuery(".change_color h2").each(...)`

Comment: `jQuery(".change_color h2")` selects all h2 elements that are descendent of any element with the class `.change_color` and returns as an array. Then, `each()` loops through each one of the found elements.

Comment: What for? `.css(key, value)` also loops through all elements of the set and applies the style. It doesn't do this just to the first element. Pretty much all jQuery methods do that (at least when you're "writing").